# I am trying to use onLongPress in react native with expo but it isn't working

Tags: react-native, android-mapview, expo

Can anyone shed any light on why onlongPress isn't working. I am using react native with expo. MapView is imported from expo

```
<MapView.Marker
              style={styles.map}
              key={marker.pageid}
              coordinate={coords}
              description={`distance: ${marker.distance}m`}
              longPressDelay={1000}
              onLongPress={() => {
                console.log('hit');
              }}
              onPress={() =>
                this.map.fitToCoordinates(
                  [
                    {
                      latitude: this.props.latitude,
                      longitude: this.props.longitude
                    },
                    coords
                  ],
                  {
                    edgePadding: {
                      top: 150,
                      right: 5,
                      bottom: 5,
                      left: 10
                    },
                    animated: true
                  }
                )
              }
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Marker hasn't onLongPress event :)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find that `onLongPress` event on `MapView.Marker`. You can wrap up that by other View, in that case, you will get some issue on styling so update styles accordingly.

or follow [this](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2002#issuecomment-368519983) approach